# Getting access to a sharedInstance from within a Class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, class-method

I am converting a project to an SDK. I need to convert several instance methods to class methods. I am getting a compiler warning about using "self". The warning is "Incompatible pointer types initializing Store* with an expression of Class. This Store class is a singleton sharedInstance.

I have method like this in my class Store:

```
+ (void) dispatchStoreSource {

__weak Store *ref = self;  <--- issue is here

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *things = [ref fetchThings:&error];

    //dispatch back to main queue
    if (![ref updateSource:source forUser:user error:&error]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            result(nil, error);
        });
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            result(source, nil);
        });
    }
  });


}
```

What is the proper way to fix this? Should it I do this?

```
 __weak Store *ref = [Store sharedInstance];
```

Comment: Why convert? Why not simply wrap with class methods which call the instance methods?

Comment: Can you expand on why one wrapping would be better?

Comment: Because there is little to no reason to remove the instance methods and by adding class methods to call the instance methods, and not editing the instance methods, you make more organised changes with less chance of human error...

Answer (score 2):

Your `ref` is pointer to an object of `Store` class. But `self` in your class method doesn't point to an allocated object of your class (= your singleton), it's your Class, IOW `Store` (not object, but Class). If you have implemented `sharedInstance` class method, like this ...

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
  static Story *instance;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    instance = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return instance;
}
```

... just do this `ref = [self sharedInstance];`

Comment: I did this as you were answering and it removes the warning. But now in the [ref updateSource..] call it is barfing because using [ref updateSource..] is an instance call not a class call. How do I go about fixing that if I want updateSource to remain a class method?  Can I just forget sharedInstance/ref var and use [self class]?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should go with  __weak Store *ref = [Store sharedInstance];

Otherwise Let's use your original static reference of Store.

Example :

```
  static Store = _store = nil;

  __weak Store * ref = _store;
```